# Lambda: Where is executed two times

Tags: c#, lambda

Is this a Visual Studio bug or .NET runtime bug?

Consider the following code:

```
 public class DoWork
{
    public void Run()
    {
        List<Entity> items = new List<Entity>();
        items.Add(new Entity { Name = "1" });
        items.Add(new Entity { Name = "12" });
      
        int maxLength = items.Max(p => p.Name.Length);
        var temp = items.Where(p => p.Name.Length == maxLength);

        do
        {
            this.Import(items);

            temp = items.Where(p => p.Name.Length < maxLength && !p.IsImported);
            // If you use a quick watch, you will see just one item correctly

            maxLength = temp.Count() > 0 ? temp.Max(p => p.Name.Length) : 0;
            // Here, when you set maxLength, you will notice that VS will break into lambda body above

            // Here temp is empty, but if you use the final ToList it works:
            // temp = items.Where(p => p.Name.Length < maxLength && !p.IsImported).ToList(); 

        }
        while (maxLength > 0);
    }

    private void Import(List<Entity> items)
    {
        items.Last().IsImported = true;
    }
}
```

It's a strange behavior and it's the first time I see something like that.
Is it a bug?

Comment: LINQ results are lazily evaluated, i.e. your query won't be executed until it's needed. With `.ToList()`, the query must run, otherwise it won't be possible to generate a list of the results.

Comment: `temp.Count() > 0` is much more expensive than `temp.Any()` which gives the same result.

Comment: @BenVoigt the implementation of `Count()` [does take into account](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Count.cs) if the underlining type is List, Array, etc and then call `.Count`, `.Length`, etc respectively, before then ultimately iterating and counting if the type does not have a counter. `.Any()` performs the same check too in its implementation. At the end of the day its probably better to use `.Any()` if you cant control the collection type, but `.Count()` is no less efficient when dealing with List/Array

Comment: @maccettura: The input collection was a lazy `IEnumerable` from `Where()`.  Generally when a where condition is involved, it's necessary to actually filter the data to get the final count (exception: if there is an index compatible with the filter condition).  It doesn't matter that the collection fed into `Where` was a `List`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't pay attention to the `.Where()` and I am happy to be corrected, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not a bug - `temp` is just a *query* that does not get executed until you actually *use* it. So when you do:

```
maxLength = temp.Count() > 0 ? temp.Max(p => p.Name.Length) : 0;
```

The query actually gets executed *twice*.  If you want to run the full query you could do:

```
temp = items.Where(p => p.Name.Length < maxLength && !p.IsImported).ToList();
```

But since you are looping and running multiple similar queries it's not completely clear if running the queries twice is actually a problem.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem. However it's a strange behavior, even without a ToList() it's a in memory list and it shouldn't get execute every time it is used. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Yes it should. How does it know that the contents of `items` doesn't change between executions? If you want static results you need to store them in a concrete collection.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `temp = items.Where(...)` only sets up a query but does not evaluate it; however, both `Count()` and `Max()` will. Note that `temp` is not a collection!

You could use this instead to enumerate the list only once:

```cs
maxLength = temp.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(p => p?.Name.Length ?? 0);
```

`DefaultIfEmpty` returns a sequence containing only one `null` element (assuming that `Entity` is a class), when the list is empty. In `p => p?.Name.Length ?? 0` if `p` is `null`, the `?.` [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) returns `null` but does not throw a null-reference exception and otherwise the `Name`. The [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `??` turns a possible `null` left-hand operator into the right-hand operator (`0` here).